# Trying to merge two results of SQL queries - ToDoList App

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, left-join

I am trying to merge two results of two queries in MYSQL using PHP, but I am puzzled how to do it! I am using PDO. I am programming for a hobby and am trying to make a to do list app just like a Trello board. However, I just can't figure out how to merge two results from different tables in a database.

The idea is as follows:

I have a table called 'task_lists' with the content:

```
'list_id => 1, list_name = 'listOne'
'list_id => 2, list_name = 'listTwo'
```

And a table called 'tasks':

```
task_id => 1, list_id => 1, task_name => 'taskOfListOne', duration => 5, is_done => 1
task_id => 2, list_id => 1, task_name => 'anotherTaskOfListOne', duration => 5, is_done => 1
task_id => 3, list_id => 2, task_name => 'taskOfListTwo', duration => 10, is_done => 0
```

And I am trying to create an array that is merged between the two results as something like:
(I know this is a rough picture of how the array is supposed to look like)

```
$result = [array]
[list_id] = 1, [list_name] = 'listOne' => 
                     [array][list_id] = 1, ['task_name] = taskOfListOne,[duration] = 5, ['is_done'] => 1
                     [array][list_id] = 1, ['task_name] = anotherTaskOfListOne,[duration] = 5, ['is_done'] => 1
[list_id] = 2, [list_name] = 'listTwo' =>
                     [array][list_id] = 2, ['task_name] = taskOfListTwo,[duration] = 5, ['is_done'] => 1
```

Is this even possible? I have tried a Union sql query and methods like nested foreach statements, but none of them worked for me. Am I missing something here?

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried left join using list_id?

Comment: Efficent way to resolve it is use JOIN in your SQL.

Comment: @besciualex, thank you very much! But how do I get rid of  the duplicate values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a left join?

```
SELECT TL.`list_id`, TL.`list_name`, T.`task_name`, T.`duration`  
FROM task_lists AS TL
LEFT JOIN tasks as T ON TL.`list_id` = T.`list_id`
```

And then in PHP you build the array in the format you want.

**Later edit:**
Simple PHP example to parse SQL data as you asked (to remove duplicated info):

```
<?php
// $mysql_rows -> here is your query result, fetched as associative array
$filtered_array = array();
foreach ($mysql_rows as $row){

    // Initiate record if is not already initiated
    if (!isset($filtered_array[ $row['list_id'] ])){
        $filtered_array[ $row['list_id'] ] = array(
            'list_id'   => $row['list_id'],
            'list_name' => $row['list_name'],
            'tasks'     => array()
        );
    }

    // Add tasks
    $filtered_array[ $row['list_id'] ]['tasks'][] = array(
        'task_name'  => $row['task_name'],
        'duration'   => $row['duration'],
        'is_done '   => $row['is_done ']
    );
}

// Optional: if you want to remove list_id from $filtered_array key names, uncomment the next line
// $filtered_array = array_values($filtered_array);
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this. How do I get rid of the duplicate values? Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: @Springsteen91 I added a simple example how to parse your data using PHP.

Comment: thank you sir, you are a genius. This worked like a charm :)